# ImportError when package is symlinked on Windows

Tags: python, windows

Python reports an import error, even when a valid package exists on
sys.path, if that package is a symlink directory and would otherwise be
importable.

I suspect that the underlying import routines have some assumptions
about the file system that exclude symlinked directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a known issue on Windows - http://bugs.python.org/issue6727 you may want to try the patches attached to that issue.

Comment: Well I did find that blog and used the patches as well. It's still not working. Hoping to pick the brains of a stackGenius :)